# Batch that deletes multiple directories/folders containing spaces

Tags: batch-file, directory, spaces

I am trying to write a batch that deletes multiple directories/folders in a directory

I am using

```
for /D %f in (*) do rmdir %f /s /q
```

Now this works and deletes folder names that dont contain a space.

I recieve this message after running the above command for the folders that do.

```
d:\test\testworld\rmdir remove me /s /q
```

> The system cannot find the file specified.
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

Most of the folders contain spaces. Is there anyway i could change the command to include folders with spaces?

Answer (score 4):

use **quotes**.

```
rmdir remove me /s /q
```

fails, but

```
rmdir "remove me" /s /q
```

works.

The change to your command line would be `for /D %f in (*) do rmdir "%f" /s /q`

Comment: Sean thank you very much i spent 18 hours looking around the web for this answer. you solved it in 1 hour. your a god cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can use "  double quotation mark like `rmdir "remove me" /s /q`